# Distributivity of `subst`

Tags: equality, agda, dependent-type

Suppose I have a transitive relation `~`with two endomaps `f` and `g`.
Assuming `f` and `g` agree everywhere and `f a ~ f b ~ f c`
then there are two ways to show `g a ~ g c`:
transform each `f` into a `g` by the given equality then apply 
transitivity,
or apply transitivity then transform along the equality.
Are the resulting proofs identical? Apparently so,

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

postulate A : Set
postulate _~_  : A → A → Set
postulate _⟨~~⟩_ : ∀{a b c} → a ~ b → b ~ c → a ~ c
postulate f g : A → A

subst-dist : ∀{a b c}{ef : f a ~ f b}{psf : f b ~ f c} → (eq : ∀ {z} → f z ≡ g z)
     → 
         subst₂ _~_ eq eq ef ⟨~~⟩ subst₂ _~_ eq eq psf 
       ≡ subst₂ _~_ eq eq (ef ⟨~~⟩ psf)

subst-dist {a} {b} {c} {ef} {psf} eq rewrite eq {a} | eq {b} | eq {c} = refl
```

I just recently learned about the `rewrite` keyword and thought it might help here; apparently it does. However, I honestly do not understand what is going on here. I've used `rewrite` other times, with comprehension. However, all these `subst`s are confusing me.

I'd like to know

- if is there a simplier way to obtain `subst-dist`? Maybe something similar in the libraries?
- what is going on with this particular usage of `rewrite`
- an alternate proof of `subst-dist` without using rewrite (most important)
- is there another way to obtain `g a ~ g c` without using `subst`?
- what are some of the downsides of using heterogeneous equality, it doesn't seem like most people are fond of it. (also important)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

`rewrite` is just a sugared `with`, which is just sugared "top-level" pattern matching. See in [Agda’s documentation](http://agda.readthedocs.org/en/latest/language/with-abstraction.html).

> what are some of the downsides of using heterogeneous equality, it
>   doesn't seem like most people are fond of it. (also important)

This is OK

```
types-equal : ∀ {α} {A B : Set α} {x : A} {y : B} -> x ≅ y -> A ≡ B
types-equal refl = refl
```

this is OK as well

```
A-is-Bool : {A : Set} {x : A} -> x ≅ true -> A ≡ Bool
A-is-Bool refl = refl
```

This is an error

```
fail : ∀ {n m} {i : Fin n} {j : Fin m} -> i ≅ j -> n ≡ m
fail refl = {!!}

-- n != m of type ℕ
-- when checking that the pattern refl has type i ≅ j
```

because `Fin n ≡ Fin m` doesn't immediately imply `n ≡ m` (you can make it so by enabling `--injective-type-constructors`, but that [makes Agda anti-classical](http://agda.chalmers.narkive.com/LcWpyGbW/agda-with-the-excluded-middle-is-inconsistent)) (`Fin n ≡ Fin m -> n ≡ m` is [provable](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/Fin-injective.agda) though).

Originally Agda permitted to pattern match on `x ≅ y` when `x` and `y` have non-unifiable types, but that allows to write weird things like (quoting from [this](https://code.google.com/p/agda/issues/detail?id=292) thread)

```
  P : Set -> Set
  P S = Σ S (\s → s ≅ true)

  pbool : P Bool
  pbool = true , refl

  ¬pfin : ¬ P (Fin 2)
  ¬pfin ( zero , () )
  ¬pfin ( suc zero , () )
  ¬pfin ( suc (suc ()) , () )

  tada : ¬ (Bool ≡ Fin 2)
  tada eq = ⊥-elim ( ¬pfin (subst (\ S → P S) eq pbool ) )
```

> Saizan    or maybe it's just ignoring the types and comparing the constructor names?
>
> pigworker Saizan: that's exactly what I think is happening
>
> Andread Abel:
>
> - If I slighly modify the code, I can prove Bool unequal Bool2, where true2, false2 : Bool2 (see file ..22.agda)
> - However, if I rename the constructors to true, false : Bool2, then suddenly I cannot prove that Bool is unequal to Bool2 anymore (see
>     other file). So, at the moment Agda2 compares apples and oranges in
>     certain situations. ;-)

So in order to pattern match on `i ≅ j`, where `i : Fin n, j : Fin m`, you first need to unify `n` with `m`

```
OK : ∀ {n m} {i : Fin n} {j : Fin m} -> n ≡ m -> i ≅ j -> ...
OK refl refl = ...
```

That's the main drawback of heteregeneous equality: you need to provide proofs of equality of indices everywhere. Usual `cong` and `subst` are non-indexed, so you also have to provide indexed versions of them (or use even more annoying `cong₂` and `subst₂`).

There is no such problem with "heteroindexed" (I don't know if it has a proper name) equality

```
data [_]_≅_ {ι α} {I : Set ι} {i} (A : I -> Set α) (x : A i) : ∀ {j} -> A j -> Set where
  refl : [ A ] x ≅ x
```

e.g.

```
OK : ∀ {n m} {i : Fin n} {j : Fin m} -> [ Fin ] i ≅ j -> n ≡ m
OK refl = refl
```

More generally, whenever you have `x : A i, y : A j, p : [ A ] x ≅ y`, you can pattern match on `p` and `j` will be unified with `i`, so you don't need to carry an additional proof of `n ≡ m`.

Heterogeneous equality, as it presented in Agda, is also [inconsistent with the univalence axiom](https://lists.chalmers.se/pipermail/agda/2015/007402.html).

**EDIT**

Pattern matching on `x : A, y : B, x ≅ y` is equal to pattern matching on `A ≡ B` and then changing every `y` in a context to `x`. So when you write

```
fail : ∀ {n m} {i : Fin n} {j : Fin m} -> i ≅ j -> n ≡ m
fail refl = {!!}
```

it's the same as

```
fail' : ∀ {n m} {i : Fin n} {j : Fin m} -> Fin n ≡ Fin m -> i ≅ j -> n ≡ m
fail' refl refl = {!!}
```

but you can't pattern match on `Fin n ≡ Fin m`

```
fail-coerce : ∀ {n m} -> Fin n ≡ Fin m -> Fin n -> Fin m
fail-coerce refl = {!!}

-- n != m of type ℕ
-- when checking that the pattern refl has type Fin n ≡ Fin m
```

like you cannot pattern match on

```
fail'' : ∀ {n m} -> Nat.pred n ≡ Nat.pred m -> n ≡ m
fail'' refl = {!!}

-- n != m of type ℕ
-- when checking that the pattern refl has type Nat.pred n ≡ Nat.pred m
```

In general

```
f-inj : ∀ {n m} -> f n ≡ f m -> ...
f-inj refl = ...
```

works only if `f` is obviously injective. I.e. if `f` is a series of constructors (e.g. `suc (suc n) ≡ suc (suc m)`) or computes to it (e.g. `2 + n ≡ 2 + m`). Type constructors (which `Fin` is) are not injective because that would make Agda anti-classical, so you cannot pattern on `Fin n ≡ Fin m` unless you enable `--injective-type-constructors`.

Indices unify for

```
data [_]_≅_ {ι α} {I : Set ι} {i} (A : I -> Set α) (x : A i) : ∀ {j} -> A j -> Set where
  refl : [ A ] x ≅ x
```

because you don't try to unify `A i` with `A j`, but instead explicitly carry indices in the type of `[_]_≅_`, which make them available for unification. When indices are unified, both types become the same `A i` and it's possible to proceed like with propositional equality.

**EDIT**

One another problem with heterogeneous equality is that it's not fully heterogeneous: in `x : A, y : B, x ≅ y` `A` and `B` must be in the same universe. The treatment of universe levels in `data` definitions has been changed recently and now we can define fully heterogeneous equality:

```
data _≅_ {α} {A : Set α} (x : A) : ∀ {β} {B : Set β} -> B -> Set where
  refl : x ≅ x
```

But this doesn't work

```
levels-equal : ∀ {α β} -> Set α ≅ Set β -> α ≅ β
levels-equal refl = refl

-- Refuse to solve heterogeneous constraint Set α : Set (suc α) =?=
-- Set β : Set (suc β)
```

because Agda doesn't think `suc` is injective

```
suc-inj : {α β : Level} -> suc α ≅ suc β -> α ≅ β
suc-inj refl = refl

-- α != β of type Level
-- when checking that the pattern refl has type suc α ≅ suc β
```

If we postulate it, then we can prove `levels-equal`:

```
hcong : ∀ {α β δ} {A : Set α} {B : Set β} {D : Set δ} {x : A} {y : B}
      -> (f : ∀ {γ} {C : Set γ} -> C -> D) -> x ≅ y -> f x ≅ f y
hcong f refl = refl

levelOf : ∀ {α} {A : Set α} -> A -> Level
levelOf {α} _ = α

postulate
  suc-inj : {α β : Level} -> suc α ≅ suc β -> α ≅ β

levels-equal : ∀ {α β} -> Set α ≅ Set β -> α ≅ β
levels-equal p = suc-inj (suc-inj (hcong levelOf p))
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! Why is `tada` considered 'weird'?

Also, `fail` and `OK` seem nearly identical and I'm not sure why carrying the index-function `A` unifies the indices. I mean with hetero equality we know the type of the arguments since it is implicit, why is that not sufficient for unifying indices?

Comment: @Musa Al-hassy, `tada` is weird, because it compares constructor names of different types. That would work in LISP or PHP, but not in a formal language. If you have `C : D1` and `C : D2` it doesn't make any sense to compare one `C` with the other — those are different things even if they look similar. I edited the answer.

Comment: woah; I really appreciate your replies. I've never given much thought to how things are unified or rewritten --I mostly play with Agda for math's sake, not programming, and seldom run into such errors. Could you link me to any good reads on learning more about how Agda unifies things and rewrite them. Thanks!

Comment: @Musa Al-hassy, there is Ulf Norell's [thesis](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~ulfn/papers/thesis.pdf), but it's from 2007 and I doubt it describes the current machinery. There are papers about dynamic pattern unification (like this [one](http://adam.gundry.co.uk/pub/pattern-unify/pattern-unification-2012-07-10.pdf)), but they are more for language implementators rather than users. I don't know any manual that would simply describe what you can and what you can't do. Also, I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank-you for your help :-)